# Error: Inserting multiple values i get this error ORA-00911: invalid character

Tags: oracle-xe

Im a first year student distance learning student who is experiencing problems with me building my database.

The error i get is ORA-00911: invalid character when i do the following:

```
INSERT INTO ORDER_LINE
VALUES
('21608','AT94',11,21.95);
INSERT INTO ORDER_LINE
VALUES
('21610','DR93',1,495.00);
INSERT INTO ORDER_LINE
VALUES
('21610','DW11',1,399.99);
INSERT INTO ORDER_LINE
VALUES
('21613','KL62',4,329.95);
INSERT INTO ORDER_LINE
VALUES
('21614','KT03',2,595.00);
INSERT INTO ORDER_LINE
VALUES
('21617','BV06',2,794.95);
INSERT INTO ORDER_LINE
VALUES
('21617','CD52',4,150.00);
INSERT INTO ORDER_LINE
VALUES
('21619','DR93',1,495.00);
INSERT INTO ORDER_LINE
VALUES
('21623','KV29',2,1290.00);
```

I have noticed that when I insert the values one by one all seems to be fine. The problem somehow occurs when i want to insert more than one value at a time.

The forums have tons of similar problems but because im a NOOB i cant see where i have gone wrong. I have retyped everything because i though i may have made a mistake somewhere but still experience this problem.

Comment: What front-end are you using?

Comment: Oracle 10g Express Edition

Comment: What is the front-end application that you are using to interact with your database?  SQL Developer?  SQL*Plus?  Something else?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue using Toad to Oracle 10g.
You have to put your insert queries between BEGIN and END:

```
BEGIN
INSERT INTO ORDER_LINE VALUES ('21608','AT94',11,21.95);
INSERT INTO ORDER_LINE VALUES ('21610','DR93',1,495.00);
END;
```